# How to create a goal in Google Analytics with respect to ONLY page traffic by Organic Search (Google)?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, goals

I am considering search traffic to be the important aspect of my goal. However, I find no way to add this criteria to consider goal Only and only if the traffic comes by organic search.

I also have one added query : I filtered these referrals to NOT to count in my stats.

- semalt.semalt.com
- buttons-for-website.com
- forum.topic57138259.darodar.com
- make-money-online.7makemoneyonline.com

I filtered like for eg : button-for-website/com

But they are yet counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the goals, you can easily reach it with the existing account by choosing the "Organic Traffic" segment at the top of the page while you are viewing the goals report. (remove "All Segments" segment.).

Another option would be to create a new View, that will filter the data to include the organic traffic only, but in my mind it is more cumbersome. Create a new view by clicking on "Admin", and then "Create new view" in the most right column's dropdown menu, where you can see the name of you current view. Then, set the following filter:

[image: organic only filter]

As for excluding traffic - how did you set the filter?

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering, 

How to set this? 

Another option would be to create a new View, that will filter the data to include the organic traffic only, but in my mind it is more cumbersome.

Comment: I have added instructions to do so in the answer above. Hope that helps.